# Admin category form tabs sorting issue

Tags: magento2

If you add any custom category attribute into any default Category Group or any Custom Group using ui_component its working good, but sorting order is mess up.

default general tab comes after on which tab you have added attribute see below screenshot. i have added custom category attribute into content tab so default general tab comes after this.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Solution is override core category_form.xml, 
Path

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

into your theme and add `sortOrder="5" on <fieldset name="general">`

**Like :**

```
<fieldset name="general" sortOrder="5">
```

Thanks